# Viewing Hypergraphs in SageMath

Tags: plot, graph, hypergraph

I am trying to visualise the hyperedges of the complete 3-uniform hypergraph on 13 vertices, so then I can colour them. I am aware that it will be busy and incomprehensible, but that is the point I am trying to show.

I have tried manually creating the hypergraph using Tikz in LaTex, but there are too many edges and I wondered if there was a way in SageMath.

Answer (score 0):

As you observe, drawing hypergraphs is tricky in general if you are looking for tidy intuitive and clean drawings.  I think (but please correct me if I am wrong) that, since you are expecting the picture to be too noisy, part of your question is about automating it because your hypergraph has 286 hyperedges.

Mathematica has a function `CommunityGraphPlot` which I have seen used to make [*pretty* nice hypergraph drawings](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58716/how-can-i-construct-and-visualize-a-hypergraph).  As far as I can tell Sagemath does not have a direct equivalent, but you might be able to use some of the code used to make a [Venn diagram in Sagemath](https://wiki.sagemath.org/interact/misc#AnInteractiveVennDiagram).

There has been some discussion and work to add hypergraph visualization to the [Graphviz Graph Visualization Tools](https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues/1911).  SageMath has an [interface to Graphviz](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/spkg/graphviz.html).  Alternatively there is a python [graphviz](https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz) library (confusingly given the same name as the non-python software it is interfacing to) to interface with Graphviz and it could be imported and used in SageMath.

Alessandro Angioi has some good discussion of ways to [visualize hypergraphs with python](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-visualize-hypergraphs-with-python-and-networkx-the-easy-way-4fe7babdf9ae)

P.J. Rogers has a site dedicated to thinking about ways to [automate drawing Venn diagrams](https://www.eulerdiagrams.com/)

R also has a package [`eulerr`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/eulerr/versions/7.0.0) which can be used to visualize set systems.  It can be utilized from within Sagemath.